# Flexbox full width grid with same columns width

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to render a flexbox grid (multi-lines) which should be 100% width of his container.

Here is what I did:

```
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list .item {
  flex-basis: 235px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 12px;
  min-width: 225px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/fjr0dxs3/

But if a second line appear, if it has less columns than the first line, is it possible to make them with an equal width as the first line without using % width sizes?

Comment: Remove flex grow

Comment: If I remove flex grow, the grid is not 100% width.

Comment: Well the grid is 100% but your items will respect the width you have given it, anyway check those duplicate questions